# Google Earth Engine: Multiple Chart Title Undefined

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to create multiple charts from NDVI data and name them per location. but when I want to display the chart title, the location cannot be defined. Where does the error lie?

```
//Point known locations for NDVI
var p1 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.57539510901834, -2.362381045840717), {'label': 'SCM_I5I6_2022-01'});
var p2 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.576489, -2.363431), {'label': 'SCM_I5I6_2022-02'});
var union1 = ee.FeatureCollection([p1, p2],{'name': 'SCM_I5I6_2022'});

var p3 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.596284, -2.349884), {'label': 'SCM_F10B_2022'});
var union2 = ee.FeatureCollection([p3],{'name': 'SCM_F10B_2022'});

var p4 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.597183, -2.349885), {'label': 'SCM_F10_2022-01'});
var p5 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.597184, -2.348981), {'label': 'SCM_F10_2022-02'});
var union3 = ee.FeatureCollection([p4, p5],{'name': 'SCM_F10_2022'});

var p6 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604485, -2.341752), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2023-01'});
var p7 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.603486, -2.340847), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2023-02'});
var p8 = ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604386, -2.339944), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2023-03'});
var union4 = ee.FeatureCollection([p6, p7,p8],{'name': 'SCM_D12_2023'});

var p9= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604385, -2.340848), {'label': 'SCM_D12_2022'});
var union5 = ee.FeatureCollection([p9],{'name': 'SCM_D12_2022'});

var p10= ee.Feature(
    ee.Geometry.Point(115.604387, -2.339039), {'label': 'SCM_C12/D12_2023'});
var union6 = ee.FeatureCollection([p10],{'name': 'SCM_C12/D12_2023'});


// Map a function over Sentinel 2 collection to add an NDVI band.
var withNDVI = s2.map(function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
});
var geom = [union1, union2, union3, union4, union5, union6];
for (var i=0; i<geom.length; i++){
  var tempTimeSeries = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: withNDVI.select('NDVI'),
    regions: geom[i],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale: 200,
    xProperty: 'system:time_start',
    seriesProperty: 'label'
  });
  tempTimeSeries.setChartType('ScatterChart');
  tempTimeSeries.setOptions({
    title: 'Average NDVI Table ' + geom[i].getInfo().features[0].properties['name'],
    hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}},
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Index'
    },
    lineWidth: 1,
    pointSize: 4,
    series: {
      0: {color: COLOR.RED},
      1: {color: COLOR.GREEN},
      2: {color: COLOR.BLUE},
      3: {color: COLOR.YELLOW},
      4: {color: COLOR.PINK},
      5: {color: COLOR.BLACK},
      6: {color: COLOR.PURPLE},
      7: {color: COLOR.AQUA}
    }
  });
  
  print(tempTimeSeries);  
}
var points = [union1,union2,union3,union4,union5,union6];
for (var j =0;j<points.length;j++){
  Map.addLayer(points[j], {color: COLOR.PURPLE}, 'Points');
}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you want to use the `name` of the `FeatureCollection` or the `label` of the first `Feature` as the chart title? Currently you're trying to use the `name` of the first `Feature`, but your features don't have that property which is why you're getting `undefined`. Your feature collections *also* don't have a `name` property because you're not setting them quite right - try using the `set` method instead of passing the properties into the constructor.

Comment: where i can place set method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the `name` property of each `FeatureCollection`, you'll need to use the `set` method instead of passing the properties into the constructor. For example:

```js
var union1 = ee.FeatureCollection([p1, p2]).set({'name': 'SCM_I5I6_2022'};
```

Next, you're currently setting the chart title based on the properties of the feature instead of the collection. To use the collection instead, try:

```js
title: 'Average NDVI Table ' + geom[i].getInfo().properties['name']
```

Comment: its work sir. thank you very much